# How to build a heap with given elements stored in leafs?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

I have n numbers and I need to build a heap data structure such that all n numbers will be stored in leaf nodes of the heap and  all internal nodes will store the minimum number stored in the left or right subtree rooted at that internal node.

Please suggest me an efficient algorithm.

Comment: It would be good if you post your own solution first. It will then be easier for someone to make it efficient or suggest different solution

Comment: I don't understand. What should be in the other parts of the heap apart from leaves if all `n` numbers are stored in the leaves?

Comment: I think that having data stored only in the leaf nodes, and not in the internal nodes by definition makes this no longer a heap.

Answer (score 0):

You can base your data-structure on the idea of Winner Trees. Have a look at the link and see how it operates.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tournament-tree-and-binary-heap/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking ? Here the children of node i are 2*i and 2*i+1.Also assumed that n is a power of 2 but it can be generalized.

```
int* create_heap(int* input , int n ){

    int * heap = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*2*n);

    for(int i = n ; i<2*n ; i++){
       heap[i] = a[i-n];
    }

    for(int i=n-1 ; i>0 ; i--){
        heap[i] = heap[2*i] < heap[2*i+1] ? heap[2*i] : heap[2*i+1];
    }
    return heap;

}
```